# sbt-native-packager packaged project's dependency fails to find config value

Tags: sbt-native-packager, typesafe-config

I have a Scala project with numerous dependencies. One of them requires a setting which is not in its own application.conf, but in other dependency's application.conf. When I run the project with `sbt run` everything is fine, however, when I run a packaged deb service or a bin script from target/universal/stage/bin, I get an error: `com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'roadmaps'`. Two dependencies have this setting in application.conf inside their jars. When I moved the setting from application.conf into reference.conf and re-published the dependency, then re-packaged my project, the packaged version worked. 
So why is my setting not picked up from application.conf in dependency's jar and why exactly should I keep library configuration in reference.conf, aside from the fact that it has lowest precedence among config files?

Comment: Can you give a minimal `build.sbt` reproducing this? This sounds more like a configuration problem ( if a configuration key is missing ). Checkout https://github.com/typesafehub/config and debug your configuration to see where the missing keys come if you start your app with `sbt run`.

Comment: I have this 'roadmaps' key in application.conf in two jars with dependencies (it is the same in both files). Why is it not picked up by packaged service?

Comment: Multiple `application.conf`s maybe loaded differently during runtime. Debug the typesafe config when and from where stuff gets loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Dconfig.trace=loads` helped me find an answer. When I `sbt run` a project that `dependsOn` other projects, it loads first its own `application.conf`, then those packaged in jars of its direct dependencies (this is where `'roadmaps'` setting comes from), then `reference.conf`s of the dependencies. When I add `bashScriptExtraDefines += """addJava "-Dconfig.file=${app_home}/../conf/application.conf""""` into build.sbt, package the project with `stage` and run it from the script in `target/universal/stage/bin`, it only loads the specified `application.conf` and then proceeds to `reference.conf`s.